# How to fetch file from shared to other folders in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a shared folder, wherein I created one more folder for activities inside the shared folder. Now in activities folder I had just given html and CSS to be fetched to the other folder called User.
But i face error as

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '../shared/activities'.

When i click on a button in user page.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Folder Structure:

```
app
  - User
  - Shared
    -- activities
```

HTML:

```
<a class="list-group-item justify-content-between clr-blk" routerLink="/auditlog" routerLinkActive="active">
   <span>Activities List</span>
</a>
```

Comment: it should be `./shared/activities`

Comment: I think the case of 'S' in shared is different.

Comment: @Sravan no that is not working

Comment: can you please share your routes?

Comment: ya i will share

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Error: Cannot find module './shared/activities.

Comment: you are using lazy routing and do u have activity module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error I can see that `activity` module is not present.

Since you are not having `activity` module, `loadChildren` and lazy routing wont work for it.

```
You should use { path: 'activity', component: activityComponent, data: {} }
```

So your routing moudle becomes:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'; 

import { activityComponent } from '../shared/activities';

const routes: Routes = [ 
    { 
        path: 'activity', 
        component: activityComponent, 
        data: {} 

    }
]; 

@NgModule({ 
    imports: [ 
        RouterModule.forChild(routes) 
    ], 
    exports: [ 
    RouterModule 
    ], 
    providers: [ 
    ] 
}) 

export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks alot, you saved my time by showing my mistakes